# Is there a name for this iterative procedure for estimating a parameter using MSE?

Tags: probability, statistics, terminology

Suppose $X_1, \cdots X_n$ are $\mathcal{N}(A, \sigma^2)$ random variables, with some unknown mean $A$. Let $\hat{A} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_n$ be their sample mean, and let $a$ be some real number. Then the MSE of the estimator $a\hat{A}$ is
$$\text{MSE}(a\hat{A}) = a^2\frac{\sigma^2}{n} + (a-1)^2A^2.$$
If we differentiate and solve for the value of $a$ which minimizes the above, we get $$a_{\text{opt}} = \frac{A^2}{A^2 + \sigma^2/n}.$$
The estimator $a_{\text{opt}}\hat{A}$ has smaller MSE than the sample mean, but is impractical to use because we don't know $A$. Consider the following simple procedure to estimate $A$:

1. Guess the value of $a_{\text{opt}}$ and call it ${a_{\text{opt}}}^{(1)}$, for example ${a_{\text{opt}}}^{(1)} = 1$.
2. Estimate $A$ by drawing a random sample from the distribution of ${a_{\text{opt}}}^{(1)}\hat{A}$. Call this $A_1$.
3. Compute ${a_{\text{opt}}}^{(2)} = \frac{(A_1)^2}{(A_1)^2 + \sigma^2/n}$.
4. Repeat.

Is this a reasonable procedure for estimating $A$? If I think of this procedure as an estimator, how could I compute its expectation and variance? Does this procedure have a name?